# Unable to rebase git svn repo through cron job

Tags: cron, git-svn

I tried to update git svn repo (git svn rebase) with cron job, but I get this error.

```
usage: git-cat-file [-t|-s|-e|-p|<type>] <sha1>
error closing pipe: Broken pipe at /usr/local/libexec/git-core//git-svn line 4290
cat-file --batch: command returned error: 129
```

I've added git path in cron script, seems not helping.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/libexec/git-core/
```

git svn rebase is working properly when I login with bash. What else should I do to make it run as cron job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it is still a PATH problem. After I copied exact PATH from bash env, problem solved.

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/libexec/git-core/
```